# Qual tipo de função devo usar?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação onde quando o valor de uma variável bool muda para false ele deve rodar um script. Devo usar o background_work para fazer isso? Se sim, como devo usa-lo? E se não, como devo fazer?

Comment: Facaria mais fácil se você adicionasse o código na pergunta.

Comment: Se você quiser que esse código ("script") rode em segundo plano, sim, você poderia usar o componente BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Por que você não coloca no `setter` esse comportamento? Atenderia perfeitamente o que você deseja. Mas sem código ou contexto fica difícil tentar ajudar além disso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Os setters nao devem "rodar scripts" quando um valor é atribuido á propriedade. Se voce quiser mesmo ir por esse meio voce pode, mas convém implentar `INotifyPropertyChanged`, isto mais uma vez resultaria no uso de eventos para resolver o problema.

Comment: @BrunoCosta entendi que o notificador parece mais elegante, mas como POGer javeiro que sou, não entendi porque interceptar a alteração do valor no `setter` e tomar uma ação seria menos recomendado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Imagine que o seu "script" demora 5 minutos a rodar. Sempre que vai mudar o valor á propriedade tem que tar parado por 5 minutos? Mesmo que resolva a questao delegando a execucao por exemplo para o `TheadPool` aconselharia de fato essa prática? Provavelmente vocé vai estar misturando lógica de negócio que nao tem nada a ver como o valor da propriedade. Imagine que voce tem vários processos para executar, voce vai meter todos lá? Nao nao vai, vai implementar o `INotifyPropertyChanged` tal como eu sugeri. Ou pelo menos deveria...

Comment: Eu votei para fechar porque parece que nao houve muito esforco na pergunta. Adicionar um [mcve] poderia ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evite fazer isso. Procure outras alternativas primeiro.

A razão desta recomendação vem pelo simples fato de que você deve evitar, na máxima extensão possível, verificar ativamente uma condição .

As verificações ativas normalmente consomem mais recursos (cpu) do que verificações passivas, pelo fato que você eventualmente terá que ter uma verificação periódica (por exemplo dentro de um loop) de um determinado estado.

Já as verificações passivas normalmente recorrem a técnicas onde existe uma notificação quando determinada condição é satisfeita, isto quer dizer que pode nem sequer existir verificação se a condição já está satisfeita.

Isto não quer dizer que deve sempre usar verificações passivas. Dependendo da 
implementação as verificações passivas também podem ter custos associados, como a [troca de contexto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300167/what-is-a-context-switch) que não é propriamente uma operação barata. Mas se puder escolher entre ter o CPU a ser usado exaustivamente a verificar determinado estado durante um período longo de tempo ou fazer uma verificação passiva deverá escolher a verificação passiva.

Você pode recorrer a várias técnicas de verificação passiva.

#### Usando eventos (mecanismo de notificação):

```
public class DadosDoEvento : EventArgs
{
    public string Dados { get; set; }
}

public class PublicadorDeEventos{
    public event EventHandler<DadosDoEvento> Evento; 

    protected virtual void OnEvento(OMeuEvento e)
    {
        Evento?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
    /*Um método qualquer que chame OnEvento */
}

var publicador = new PublicadorDeEventos();
publicador.Evento += (src, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Dados);
```

#### Usando eventos (mecanismo de sincronização):

```
public class PublicadorDeEventos{

    public ManualResetEvent Evento{ get { return new ManualResetEvent(false); } }

    /*Um método qualquer que chame Evento.Set();*/
}

var publicador = new PublicadorDeEventos();
publicador.Evento.WaitOne();
```

#### Usando `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

Eu não meti esta abordagem na minha resposta inicial porque ela é um cenário especifico do uso de eventos (mecanismo de notificação) e, na minha opinião, ela não é tão simples assim de usar. Mas isso não quer dizer que ela não tem o seu mérito (talvez seja assunto para outra pergunta), mas deixo aqui um exemplo:

```
public class Modelo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _dados;
    public string Dados { 
        get {return _dados;}
        set {
            _dados = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dados));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

var modelo = new Modelo();
modelo.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.PropertyName == "Dados")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados mudaram vou executar o meu script aqui");
    }
}
```

Qual é que deve usar? Pessoalmente tenho preferência em escolher o primeiro. Normalmente a segunda alternativa fornece uma API mais difícil de usar, além de que não resolve todos os casos. Você precisa ter cuido em escolher o mecanismo adequado de sincronização e em casos especiais implementar o seu próprio mecanismo de sincronização.

Comment: bacana, consegue publicar um exemplo do `INotifyPropertyChanged` ? Obrigado

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Feito.

Comment: muito obrigado @BrunoCosta

Comment: Obrigado! @BrunoCosta